Use GCP short-lived service account credentials as application default credentials
How can I set the application default credentials to use short-lived credentials for a GCP service account?
Rationale
I want to authenticate an external continuous delivery service as a GCP service account. The GCP service account doc recommends a short-lived credential for security:

The most secure way to authenticate as a service account is to obtain short-lived credentials for the service account in the form of an OAuth 2.0 access token.

The goal is to use the short-lived token to set the application default credentials via the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable. However, I don't know how to convert the bearer token into a JSON file that works as the application default credential.
I want to use application default credentials since the binary invokes many GCP clients (storage, GKE, secret manager). There's not an easy way to manually set the credentials for each client.
What I've tried

Generate a short-lived token.

gcloud auth print-access-token --impersonate-service-account=$SA@$PROJ.iam.gserviceaccount.com


Pass the token to the continuous delivery service with an environment variable $MY_TOKEN.

Write the token to a temporary JSON file /tmp/sa-creds.json with the format {"token": "$MY_TOKEN"}.

Set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to /tmp/sa-creds.json so that client libraries will automatically use the credentials.


This fails (somewhat expectedly) since the format doesn't match the application default credential format.
Related questions

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56497979/30900 Describes that application default credentials are not credentials but a way to locate credentials. With that information, it seems unlikely that there's a way to use a token as application default credentials.


If you can (because you can use one of the providers), try to use Workload Identity Federation

You should strongly prefer ADC in any code. As you noted, ADC is a way to locate credentials but, the consequence of ADC is that your code remains loosely-coupled to credentials (and more flexible and easier to maintain as a result).

Your approach in generating a short-lived token is incorrect. Because your goal is to have your CD service authenticate, you preferably want to use Workload Identity Federation (WIF) to federate as a Service Account. If your CD isn't one of the WIF providers, you will have to run as a Service Account directly. This will require that you create a Service Account key and distribute it to the CD service where your code or some provider-provided binary is able to use ADC to authenticate to Google.

My CD provider doesn't support Workload Identity Federation. I plan to use ADC. I've used the service account key before but hoped to leverage the short-lived token.

Can you try this: Put your token (not a JSON) directly in the GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN env var, and run your workload again. I fear it will work only for terraform, but it is worth a try!

It looks like only terraform supports the token. The Go client libraries don't read that env var: https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=context:global+GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN+lang:go&patternType=keyword&sm=0
